# In Sphinx, can I register a bunch of keywords that should always be translated into links?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

My doc strings have references to other python classes that I've defined.  Every time Sphinx encounters one of these classes, I want it to insert a link to the documentation for that other class.  Is this possible in Sphinx?

Specifically, I have a doc string like:

```
'''This class contains a bunch of Foo objects'''
```

I could write:

```
'''This class contains a bunch of :class:`~foo.Foo` objects'''
```

but I would prefer that Sphinx finds all text matching `Foo` and makes it seem as though I had typed
    :class:`~foo.Foo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use macros.

In my project, I have a header file that contains all "important" classes and global functions and their abbreviation. Two example lines:

```
.. |PostItem| replace:: :class:`PostItem <hklib.PostItem>`
.. |PostNotFoundError| replace:: :class:`PostNotFoundError <hklib.PostNotFoundError>`
```

In my `rst` files, I include this header file. Then I can use the macros in any `rst` file:

```
.. include:: defs.hrst

|PostItem| is a nice class. |PostNotFoundError|, on the other hand is not.
```

(You can include docstrings from Python source files as well, using the `autogen` extension. Macros in those will be replaced as well.)

About your example: I would add `Foo` to the header file and write the docstring this way:

```
'''This class contains a bunch of |Foo| objects'''
```

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx has a huge number of interpreted text roles for this.

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects

> I want to enter Foo and have Sphinx interpret it as though I had written :class:`~foo.Foo`

That sounds impractical.  It seems like it would paralyze RST trying parse your text.  Looking for interpreted text and the few quoting rules that RST supports (`` *_|` ``) is about the limit that's practical.

What you're asking for might lead to RST taking all day to check each instance `Foo` in every possible context and reason out whether you wanted a link or not.  You'd want this only in otherwise-undecorated instances of `Foo`; trivial search and replace wouldn't work.

You can mess with docstring pre-processing.

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#docstring-preprocessing

This may allow you to try a global search-and-replace strategy on your docstring text.